# update field based on another field's updated value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following query (self-explanatory):

```
update t
    set scans = scans + 1, 
        is_active = if(count = scans, 0, is_active)
where id = 123
```

Finally `scans` get updated and actually equals to `count` but `is_active` still stays `1`.

I want whenever scans = count to deactivate entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what should be happening, [according to the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

> If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression, UPDATE uses the current value of the column. For example, the following statement sets col1 to one more than its current value:
>
> `UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1;`
>
> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result is that col1 and col2 have the same value. This behavior differs from standard SQL.
>
> `UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;`
>
> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.

Comment: well i dont think this to work, coz I need to compare to updated value of of scans. I just simplified my query for the question.

Comment: Anyway, you're updating the `scans` value with something, why can't you subtract the same value in the `if` clause for the comparison?

Comment: ya but imagine count is 3, scan was 2 and doing third update, now new scan value should be 3 and u say, compare count to 2 again no?

Comment: i think the reason might be because im running this in transaction, because i tested it without transaction and it works. what u think?

Comment: I amended the answer because that is what should be happening, according to the documentation. However, even the documentation is vague enough about it.